# how to use Queue in python?

Tags: python, queue

My code in the following encounters error.
It's an example to use Queue in python.
May I ask how to fix it?
thanks for your help in advance.

```
# coding=utf-8
from multiprocessing import Queue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q=Queue(3)
    q.put('message1')
    q.put('message2')
    print(q.full())
    q.put('message3')
    print(q.full())

    try:
        q.put("message4",True,1)
    except:
        print("the queue is full. current amount is %s"%q.qsize())
    try:
        q.put('message4')
    except:
        print("the queue is full. current amount is %s"%q.qsize())
    
    if not q.empty():
        print('get message from the queue.')
        for i in range(q.qsize()):
            print(q.get_nowait())
    if not q.full():
        q.put_nowait("message4")
```

**The output error is:**

False
True

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "process.py", line 13, in <module>
    q.put("message4",True,1)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 84, in put
    raise Full
queue.Full

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 15, in <module>
    print("the queue is full. current amount is %s"%q.qsize())
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 120, in qsize
    return self._maxsize - self._sem._semlock._get_value()
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Could you also please include the traceback error which you are facing

Comment: @Vaibhav, I have added the traceback now.

Answer (score 0):

As Víctor Terrón has suggested in a GitHub discussion, you can use his implementation:

https://github.com/vterron/lemon/blob/d60576bec2ad5d1d5043bcb3111dff1fcb58a8d6/methods.py#L536-L573

According to the doc:

> A portable implementation of multiprocessing.Queue. Because of
> multithreading / multiprocessing semantics, Queue.qsize() may raise
> the NotImplementedError exception on Unix platforms like Mac OS X
> where sem_getvalue() is not implemented. This subclass addresses this
> problem by using a synchronized shared counter (initialized to zero)
> and increasing / decreasing its value every time the put() and get()
> methods are called, respectively. This not only prevents
> NotImplementedError from being raised, but also allows us to implement
> a reliable version of both qsize() and empty().

Comment: Hi@Vaibhav, I find the problen is that the code call qsize(). I notice that even though I just write ```print("size: %s"%q.qsize())```, it also feedbacks errors.

Comment: Hi @Vaibhav,   is it enough if I just copy his classes of Queue and SharedCounter?